# Mapping through items in static query not showing any results

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Fairly new to Gatsby and React. It seems to be going fine so far, but for some reason I can't seem to map through items using the static query method in class based component.

My code is added below.

The strange thing is that the {this.props.site.siteMetadata.title} works ok, even the totalCount or primaryMenu returns data fine but the mapping through the primaryMenu just doesn't return anything.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

class Navigation extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.site.siteMetadata.title}

                {/* {this.props.primaryMenu.totalCount} */}
                {this.props.primaryMenu.edges.map((item, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <Link to={item.url} activeClassName="overlayActive">
                            {item.title}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default () => (
    <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              title
            }
          }
          primaryMenu: allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems(filter: {wordpress_id: {eq: 2}}) {
            totalCount
            edges {
              node {
                count
                items {  
                  title
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }

        }
      `}
        render={(data) => (
            <Navigation site={data.site} primaryMenu={data.primaryMenu}  />
        )}
    />
)
```

I get the following data from my graphql query so the data is there, just not pulling through

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "Site title"
      }
    },
    "primaryMenu": {
      "totalCount": 1,
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "count": 6,
            "items": [
              {
                "title": "About",
                "url": "/about/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Programs",
                "url": "/programs/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Locations",
                "url": "/locations/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Alumni",
                "url": "/alumni/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Admission",
                "url": "/admission/"
              },
              {
                "title": "Blog",
                "url": "/blog/"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: check by debugging whether you are getting some data inside that or not. Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Hi Adesh, thanks for your comment. I edited my original post with results from query

Comment: okay what I am able to see is there is certain fields under primaryMenu.edges and then under this you have node and then items. So your code should be like this.props.primaryMenu.edges.node.items.map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has node and then items under edges which have URL and title. I have corrected the code please check.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

class Navigation extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.site.siteMetadata.title}

                {/* {this.props.primaryMenu.totalCount} */}
                {this.props.primaryMenu.edges[0].node.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <Link to={item.url} activeClassName="overlayActive">
                            {item.title}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default () => (
    <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              title
            }
          }
          primaryMenu: allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems(filter: {wordpress_id: {eq: 2}}) {
            totalCount
            edges {
              node {
                count
                items {  
                  title
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }

        }
      `}
        render={(data) => (
            <Navigation site={data.site} primaryMenu={data.primaryMenu}  />
        )}
    />
)
```

Comment: Thanks Adesh, for your further comment. I had actually tried it like that also, but get the following error 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
Navigation.render
src/components/Navigation.js:9

Comment: Okay I missed one thing it's the 0 index under edges so use edges[0].node.items

Comment: Thanks Adesh, you're a star! How annoying that it was that tiny issue that had me stumped. I appreciate you helping!!!